# get content which user likes

Tags: 7, views

When a user registers in my site, the registration form asks the user on which type of food he likes, the user choses one or more from a taxonomy terms.

A user can also create content and tag them from the same taxonomy terms on the registration from.

Now I want to create a view that gets all food "content" the user likes based on what he chose in the registration form or profile.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're having trouble with?  What kind of view are you trying to create (e.g., page, block, content pane, etc.)?

Comment: I cant link the taxonomy terms that are on the registered user to be on a contexual fileter, I'm trying to create a block that gets me content based on the liking of the user

Comment: Are the terms on the content the user created or on the user?  If the terms are on the content the user created, you're going to need to use a relationship with the contextual filter.  But in such a case it might be easier to use Panels to set the argument for the contextual filter and use a content pane instead of a block.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by building a view that has relation to current user selected taxonomies. Then listing content according to that.